# Clear Webview 'X' session (cache) without clearing Webview 'Y's

Tags: webview, uwp

I have 2 webviews in my app where the user can log in at 2 different web services.
Both the services have no methods to log the user out. Calling the log-in url again result in automatic log in of the user, even after closing and reopening the app.

I can call Webview.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync(), but that results in asking for user credentials at both services.

Is there a way to clear the session (cache) of each webview separately, maybe by sending a specific request header or some other method? I want to give the user the option to log one service out so he can log in again with different credentials...

Comment: Could you please try using  [WebView.Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.settings.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT, could you advise how that settings could help with session logout? The only things I see there are "JavaScript enabled" and "Indexed DB enabled".